# Power shell to add the odd numbers in the odd lines and the even numbers in the even lines

Tags: powershell, shell

Power shell to add the odd numbers in the odd lines and the even numbers in the even line the result of each line should come in the standard output! In each line, there are at least 2 numbers. The filename is given by a parameter.

```
for example this:
1 2 3
4 5 6 
5 6 7 
7 8 9
4 6 0
the output should be 
4
10
12
8
0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file content with `Get-Content` or `cat`, and then turn it to an array by splitting on `\n`

```
$lines = (Get-Content $filepath).split('\n')
```

You can then iterate on each line and split it on ' ', and then iterate on that array and summing up the values you want

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $lines.length;$i++){
  $numsInLine = $lines[i].split(' ')
  $lineSum = 0
  for($j=0;$j -lt $numsInLine.length;$j++){
    if($numsInLine[j] % 2 -eq $i % 2){ #$i is the line number, $numsInLine[j] is a number in that line
        $lineSum++
    }
  }
  Write-Host $lineSum 
}
```

Edit: In response to Lee_Dailey's comment, % in this content is the modulo operator. x%2 returns the parity of x, which is exactly what you need here.

Also note that `%` in powershell is an alias for `ForEach-Object`.
 `%` or `ForEach-Object` in powershell is a simple for-each loop, iterates over all values in the array with a simpler syntax, no index though. 
In our case I would recommend using it instead of the second for loop only, as we use the index variable in the first (note `i` is in use). In that case, the second loop would look like:

```
$numsInLine | %{ #or $numsInLine | ForEach-Object
    if($_ % 2 -eq $i % 2){ #$_ refers to the last returned object
        $lineSum++
    }
  }
```

Note two things here:

1.`%` or `ForEach-Object` are always used after pipeline as they must recieve an InputObject. The InputObject must also be iteratable. That's how to differ between % as modulo and % as foreach.

2. `$_` is used here as the current iterated item. Our iterated item does not have a named variable refrencing it. `$_` is commonly used in pipeline and foreach loops in particular (however you can use it in any other case too).

Another logically-equal syntax is:

```
foreach($num in $numsInLine){
    if($num % 2 -eq $i % 2){
        $lineSum++
    }
  }
```

Note that here no pipeline or `$_` is needed.

Comment: neat Answer! [*grin*] i've two comments ... [1] the recommended style for teaching/helping is to NOT use any alias or short name for commands/parameters/etc  ... would you please replace the `cat` with the real name of the command? [2] you could also improve your Answer by explaining what `%` means in that context & how it works to get the desired result. [*grin*]

Comment: kool! [*grin*] i would totally replace the aliases, tho. _in my opinion_, there is simply no reason to add needless complexity to a helping/teaching situation.

Comment: Which aliases? cat was the only alias

Comment: the `%` in this >>> `$numsInLine | %{ `` <<< is an alias for `ForEach-Object`. [*grin*]